# How to capture all console error logs playwright

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

[image]

I tried all of this,

```
page.on("console", lambda msg: print(f"error: {msg.text}") if msg.type == "error" else None)
page.on("console", lambda msg: print(msg.text))
page.on("pageerror", lambda exc: print(f"uncaught exception: {exc}"))
```

Nothing works

Terminal output

```
python main.py 
/home/xxx/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/trio/_core/_multierror.py:511: RuntimeWarning: You seem to already have a custom sys.excepthook handler installed. I'll skip installing Trio's custom handler, but this means MultiErrors will not show full tracebacks.
  warnings.warn(
```

Comment: Do you get nothing on your terminal?

Comment: Nothing on terminal.

Comment: EDIT:Added terminal output

Comment: Make sure to add this before you navigate to your page (page.goto) then it will work. If not, I'd recommend to file a bug on GitHub.

Comment: Looks more like a problem with the library **trio** than **playwright**. Maybe it needs upgrading.

Comment: This code should work fine, so a complete, runnable [mcve] with all code, versions and site being manipulated is necessary to determine what the problem is.